# Python installed but not recognized in cmd ,windows commands don't work in cmd, messed path variables

Tags: python, command-line

Even after adding pythons path to both user and system path variable `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311`, I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\HP>py -version
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

also, the normal networking (windows) commands are not working like `ipconfig` and `tracert`.

i was expecting the path to get set and code on.

Comment: py --version with two dash not one dash. Output Python 3.12.0a4

Comment: py.exe is installed in the Windows directory, %windir%. Being that as it is you'd expect your windows directory to also be in the path by default. Your error indicates py.exe is not in the path

Answer (score 0):

To execute python in cmd, you should do that :

```
cd 'absolute path to your python.exe file'
python
```

Note that python folders and executable are oftenly found in the appdata directory.
To run an already prepared python script, you should write instead of only 'python' (while being in the python.exe folder using cd ofc) :

```
python 'absolutepath to your py file'
```

Edit : the quotes in the code is just because I don't know your file path, do NOT input the path as a string just put the absolute path as it is.